How do I fix website height and width on mobile in react js?
I am new to React JS, and I wrote a simple website, that looks OK on a web browser, however, my mobile appearance is very off. For some reason, the height on mobile is twice as big, and I see a huge scrollbar, which a. I don't need and b. there's no content the, so don't know why it is showing.
Here is my CSS:
.App {
  display: flex;
  min-width:  768px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #cbe6ef;
  flex-direction: column;

  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
   width: 50%;
   height: 50vh;
 }

 /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
 @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
   width: 100%;
 }
}

My App.js:
function App() {

  return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="testing" element={<BetaTesting />} />
      </Routes>
  );
}

And my Home screen:
const Home = () => {
    const mystyle = {
    backgroundImage: "url(/background.png)",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"

  }

    const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['viewed_cookie_policy']);
    return (
    <div style={ mystyle } className="App">
      <Header />
      <News />
            <Footer />
            {!cookies.viewed_cookie_policy ? <Consent /> : null}
    </div>
    );
};

This is how it looks on mobile:

If someone can tell me what I am doing wrong will be great!


If you think the below analysis + fix don't solve your problem, please edit your original question to include more detail on what you're trying to achieve.

You specified min-width: 768px; as the default width, which applies to mobile (width is only set to 50% in your first media query)
height remains 50vh even on desktop

Below is the updated code.
.App {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #cbe6ef;
  flex-direction: column;

  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
  }

  /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
  @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    width: 100%;
    
    /* Uncomment the below lines if you wish to set your
       height over the whole screen on desktops */
    /* -- */
    /* height: 100%; */
    /* min-height: 100vh; */
  }
}


Thanks, it did fix it on mobile, however now on my web browser the height is also 50% and I don't understand why?

@newbiecoder I left a fix for that too at the bottom section of the fixed CSS file, you can just uncomment it.
